# Building Android Calendar using ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to build this app
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/

I have cloned the repository then run on it ndk-build.
At first, it complained about min version mismatch after fixing it I am getting
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk

Is there an environment setup that I need in order to build it?

Comment: What makes you think a Java app: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/master/src/com/android/calendar requires the NDK? Also realize that the build system for Android Open Source Project apps is different than normal Android app development.

Comment: That is a good point the src are java yet I saw this Android.mk and I was thinking maybe I need to run the ndk-build. I tried to only import the src to new android project and it was nightmare 2 hours of trying to fixing including and missing methods or other issues .... Ideas how I can build it?

Comment: If you are doing this as a exercise, you will run into missing things. Unfortunately I can't think of any other way (i.e. new project, copy src, res and manifest) since the actual app some Google/system level stuff which would need to be removed (the backup one seems obvious). Also note that there are open-source calendars that you may be able to leverage if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw some did not like them.
I have used CalendarView as a start but when I realize that I need to support other views like week view and day view so I have started digging.
I did not like the other calendars out there...but many thanks for the support eventually I will find something useful.